# Gatsby automatically stripping all querystring

Tags: amazon-s3, gatsby

I am looking after a Gatsby site that was originally built by a company no longer around which appears to include some functionality to stop duplicate urls.

The gatsb-node.js file exports a createPages method that loads all pages from the cms and calls the createPage function for each. This includes setting the path on a page.

When viewing the site any variations of a matching url. e.g. with / without trailing slash, or query string parameters results in a redirect to whatever the path was set to. e.g. When a path is set to /about-us the following scenarios would occur...

/about-us -> Page loads

/about-us/ -> redirect to /about-us

/about-us?utm=24234 -> redirect to /about-us

Searching the solution nothing stands out for configuring this, and none of the packages installed sound like it's something they're for. I'm not a gatsby expert though.

Can someone answer:

1. Is this just normal Gatsby functionality?
2. If it is can you turn it off or create exceptions for things like UTM code?
3. If it's not normal functionality is it something people often do with Gatsby and have an idea how it might have been implemented?

The solution is Gatsby 2.21.1 and it runs out of an S3 bucket.

Locally the redirect doesn't occur but I don't know if this is just because its in dev mode or if it's actually AWS causing the redirect somehow.